# Finding XMIT Queue Depth using WebSphere MQ Classes for .Net

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to get the `Queue Depth` for a `Transmission Queue` (**XMIT** queue) using [WebSphere MQ](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-mq) Classes for .Net , can someone kindly help me giving a specific link/Pseudocode or .Net Classes/API to identify the XMIT queue depth. I have gone through the .Net API but didn't find any info on XMIT queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MQ .NET PCF interface to query queue attributes. Below is the sample code snippet.

*Note: MQ .NET PCF interface is undocumented interface and may not be supported. You will need to consult IBM.*

```
    public static void InquireQueue()
    {
        PCFMessageAgent messageAgent = null;
        try
        {
            // Create connection to queue manager
            messageAgent = new PCFMessageAgent("QM3");

            // Build Inquire command to query attributes a queue
            PCFMessage pcfMsg = new PCFMessage(MQC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q);
            pcfMsg.AddParameter(MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "TO.QM2");

            // Send request and receive response
            PCFMessage[] pcfResponse = messageAgent.Send(pcfMsg);

            // Process and print response.
            int pcfResponseLen = pcfResponse.Length;
            for (int pcfResponseIdx = 0; pcfResponseIdx < pcfResponseLen; pcfResponseIdx++)
            {
                PCFParameter[] parameters = pcfResponse[pcfResponseIdx].GetParameters();
                foreach (PCFParameter pm in parameters)
                {
                    // We just want to print current queue depth only
                    if (pm.Parameter == MQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH) 
                        Console.WriteLine("Queue Depth" + " - " + pm.GetValue());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (PCFException pcfEx)
        {
            Console.Write(pcfEx);
        }
        catch (MQException ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (messageAgent != null)
                messageAgent.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Shashi, Thanks for your reply. I am looking for a suggestion like XMIT queue is nothing but a local queue which is located in the same queue manager of a Remote queue.Can we go in this way to identify the queue depth, Get the Alias Queue Name for the Remote queue Name and identify the XMIT queue name for that and then get the Queue Depth for that respective XMIT queue?. Kindly share your thoughts

Comment: Sorry, I am not very clear on your question. If you have the queue name and queue manager name where the XMIT is located, you can determine the depth by connecting to that queue manager.