# IBM MQ / WebSphere MQ: Managing the server from .NET?

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I am trying to find, if there is any way how to configure the IBM MQ server from .NET?

Is it actually even possible to remotely control the IBM MQ in other way than Webspere UI?

Thanks.

/IP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MQ/PCF API: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q020010_.htm

Here's some examples:

- [MQ Statistics Monitoring from C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178088/mq-statistics-monitoring-from-c-net)
- [Finding XMIT Queue Depth using WebSphere MQ Classes for .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380641/finding-xmit-queue-depth-using-websphere-mq-classes-for-net)
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnetinterop/2005/12/02/pcf-with-ibms-mq-classes-for-net/
- http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=60083&sid=ae7da961b41f94662324d3627ea6cc34

Comment: I had silly hopes for some official way to support management from .NET, looks like not a priority for IBM. Thanks for info!